# Python Method Definition Using Decorators

Tags: python, methods

Can someone thoroughly explain the last line of the following code:

```
def myMethod(self):
    # do something

myMethod = transformMethod(myMethod)
```

Why would you want to pass the definition for a method through another method? And how would that even work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of function wrapping, which is when you have a function that accepts a function as an argument, and returns a new function that modifies the behavior of the original function.

Here is an example of how this might be used, this is a simple wrapper which just prints 'Enter' and 'Exit' on each call:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped():
        print 'Enter'
        result = func()
        print 'Exit'
        return result
    return wrapped
```

And here is an example of how you could use this:

```
>>> def say_hello():
...     print 'Hello'
... 
>>> say_hello()  # behavior before wrapping
Hello
>>> say_hello = wrapper(say_hello)
>>> say_hello()  # behavior after wrapping
Enter
Hello
Exit
```

For convenience, Python provides the [decorator syntax](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator) which is just a shorthand version of function wrapping that does the same thing at function definition time, here is how this can be used:

```
>>> @wrapper
... def say_hello():
...     print 'Hello'
... 
>>> say_hello()
Enter
Hello
Exit
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! I greatly appreciate how clear it was.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would you want to pass the definition for a method through another method?

Because you want to modify its behavior.

> And how would that even work?

Perfectly, since functions are first-class in Python.

```
def decorator(f):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'Before!'
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)
    print 'After!'
    return res
  return wrapper

def somemethod():
  print 'During...'

somemethod = decorator(somemethod)

somemethod()
```

Comment: Why don't you just modify the method's actual source code? Can you give an example where passing the definition of a method would be very beneficial? Lastly, how would one write the transformMethod to modify another method? Sorry about all the questions, I've never seen this type of syntax before so I'm very confused.

Comment: "Why don't you just modify the method's actual source code?" Because you may not *have* the source code, or you need to apply it to multiple functions.

Comment: @user1495015 Or maybe the modification which is done is always the same, only the part of what is actually modified is different. For this, you can happily use decorators.

Comment: memoization is a very common use case for decorators

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a decorator, a form of method/function modification which can be accomplished much easier with the special syntax for [decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).

What you describe is equivalent to

```
@transformMethod
def myMethod(self):
    # do something
```

Decorators are used very broadly, for example in the form of `@staticmethod`, `@classmethod`, `@functools.wraps()`, `@contextlib.contextmanager` etc. etc. etc.

Since a certain Python version (I think it was 2.6), classes can be decorated as well.

Both kinds of decoratiors happily allow to return objects which are not even functions or classes. For example, you can decorate a generator function in a way which turns it into a dict, a set or whatever.

```
apply = lambda tobeapplied: lambda f: tobeapplied(f())

@apply(dict)
def mydict():
    yield 'key1', 'value1'
    yield 'key2', 'value2'
print mydict

@apply(set)
def myset():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 1
    yield 4
    yield 2
    yield 7
print myset
```

What do I do here?

I create a function which takes a "thing to be applied" and in turn returns another function.

This "inner" function takes the function to be decorated, calls it and puts its result in the outer function and returns this result.

`f()` returns a generator object which is then put into `dict()` or `set()`.

Comment: No, it *is* a decorator. The `@` is just syntactic sugar for the exact same operation.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You are right. I was too close at Python's definition.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yes, but most people see decorators the other way around. Not necessarily as a generic method transform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that in Python, everything is an object.  A function is an object.  You can do the same things with a function object that you can do with other kinds of objects: store in a list, store in a dictionary, return from a function call, etc.

The usual reason for code like you showed is to "wrap" the other function object.  For example, here is a wrapper that prints the value returned by a function.

```
def print_wrapper(fn):
    def new_wrapped_fn(*args):
        x = fn(*args)
        print("return value of %s is: %s" % (fn.__name__, repr(x)))
        return x
    return new_wrapped_fn

def test(a, b):
    return a * b

test = print_wrapper(test)

test(2, 3)  # prints:  return value of test is: 6
```

This is such a useful task, and such a common task, that Python has special support for it.  Google search for "Python decorators".

Answer (score 0):

In your original question, you asked "Why would you want to pass the definition for a method through another method?" Then, in a comment, you asked "Why don't you just modify the method's actual source code?" I actually think that's a very good question, and a difficult one to answer without hand-waving, because decorators only become really useful when your code reaches a certain level of complexity. However, I think the point of decorators will become clearer if you consider the following two functions:

```
def add_x_to_sequence(x, seq):
    result = []
    for i in seq:
        result.append(i + x)
    return result

def subtract_x_from_sequence(x, seq):
    result = []
    for i in seq:
        result.append(i - x)
    return result
```

Now, these two example functions have some flaws -- in real life, for example, you'd probably just rewrite them as list comprehensions -- but let's ignore the obvious flaws for the moment, and pretend that we *must* write them this way, as `for` loops iterating over sequences. We now face the problem that our two functions do *almost* the same thing, differing only at one key moment. That means we are repeating ourselves here! And that's a problem. Now we have to maintain more lines of code, leaving more room for bugs to appear, and more room for bugs to hide once they've appeared.

One classic approach to this problem might be to create a function that *takes* a function, and applies it across a sequence, like this:

```
def my_map(func, x, seq):
    result = []
    for i in seq:
        result.append(func(i, x))
    return result
```

Now all we have to do is define specific funcs to pass to `my_map` (which is really just a specialized version of the built-in `map` function).

```
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

And we can use them like this:

```
added = my_map(sub, x, seq)
```

But this approach has its problems. It's a bit harder to read than our original stand-alone functions, for example; and every time we want to add or subtract `x` from a list of items, we have to specify the function and value as arguments. If we're doing this a lot, we'd rather have a single function name that always refers to the same action -- that would improve readability, and make it easier to understand what's happening in our code. We *could* wrap the above in *another* function...

```
def add_x_to_sequence(x, seq):
    return my_map(add, x, seq)
```

But now we're repeating ourselves again! And we're also creating a proliferation of functions, cluttering our namespace.

Decorators provide a way out of these problems. Instead of passing a function to another function *every time*, we can pass it once. First we define a wrapper function:

```
def vectorize(func):
    def wrapper(x, seq):
        result = []
        for i in seq:
            result.append(func(i, x))
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Now all we have to do is define a function and pass it to the above, wrapping it:

```
def add_x_to_sequence(a, b):
    return a + b
add_x_to_sequence = vectorize(add_x_to_sequence)
```

Or, using decorator syntax:

```
@vectorize
def add_x_to_sequence(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Now we can write many different `vectorize`d functions, and our `for` logic *for all of them* happens in just one place. Now we don't have to fix or optimize many different functions separately; all our loop-related bugs and loop-related optimizations happen in the same place; and we still get all the readability benefits of specially-defined functions.